# Manually defining external symbols with gcc

Tags: windows, gcc, linker, ld, dll-injection

I'm using DLL injection in a video game for the purpose of modding (I'm building a game API).

I want to directly access structures and variables in the EXE from my new DLL. The absolute addresses of variables are known (the EXE has a fixed image base) .

According the GNU `ld` documentation, I can use `--defsym=symbol=expression` to create a global symbol in the output file, containing the absolute address given by expression.

I can't get it to work.

If I declare the symbols as `extern` in my code, and use `ld --defsym`, I get undefined reference errors. But if I define the symbols in my code, it just uses the local (DLL) versions, not the EXE ones.

It seems the `--defsym` options are having no effect. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Update: `--defsym` works perfectly under Linux. When I try compiling on Windows using mingw, I get `undefined reference` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem.

After inspecting the assembly produced by `mingw`, I found the C symbol names are being  prefixed by an underscore. This happens on Windows, but not on Linux.

There is a `gcc` option `-fno-leading-underscore`, but this results in an undefined reference to `WinMain`.

Simply adding leading underscores to the symbol names works.

Example: if my my symbol is named `alien` in C, using `gcc --defsym=_alien=0x500000` works fine.